How much should humans get involved in fixing the environment?
What should humans be willing to pay/ give up for the harm we've done to the environment? It is no secret that humans are the cause of climate change and the only specie equipped, and conscious enough to fix the problem. Since this is the case should there not be some type of standard as to how much we should be willing to change to fix these issue. Some philosophers have gone as far as to say that humans need to willingly reduce our population size but clearly that won’t work considering the state of the world right now. Plus, think about the consequences of china’s one child policy or the roe v Wade issue happening right now. Since that isn’t the answer what is?

Widely accessible smartphones, video games, and on demand TV seem to have done more to crater China's birth rate about 5-10 times more effectively than One Child ever did...

This question seems to be asking about our opinions, but on this site questions should be about philosophy. And for moral questions, the ethical framework by which this should be answered should be stated in the question.

This gets at a core issue of climate change: how much can we actually control it going forward. Regardless of how much we've affected it in the past, how much will changing CO2 affect the go-forward situation we are in?
It seems like we've passed the point of no return on this one, and we need to move to adaptation. The energy source issue will resolve itself via basic economics.
There will be winners and losers in this new climate and we need to accept the reality of that vs trying to think we can mount some coordinated global action. We're seeing the limits of human collective decision-making -- global warming is too probabilistic, complex, and future oriented to warrant action now.
Basically, we don't care about future generations as much as we like to let on, and it makes sense since we (now) are not going to be there.
